# Internal error in debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

Can anyone help me with this error in Visual Studio 2015? When I put a breakpoint, on debug I receive this error(from the picture) and after that vshost32 stop working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTRW3.png)

Edit: that post doesn't have a correct answer. The error is still there. I try all the answers from suggested post.

Comment: Get another opinion with Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.  This forces an older debugging engine to be used, it is much more stable than the VS2015 engine.

Comment: @Marijane Mrj, Is it related to the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" option as Hans Passant's suggestion?

Comment: @Hans Passant thank you very much for your help. That solution was great. It's working now. Provide this solution like an answer.

Comment: @MarijaneMrj， Glad to know that it has been resolved.

Comment: @Hans Passant, Would you please add your comment as the answer?

Comment: @Jack - this is a dup question, answers belong in the linked dup.  You have an answer there, please copy my comment to improve it.